# How do I enable Edit and Continue in VS2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2019

Recently started a new project is VS2019 and "Edit and Continue" doesn't seem to be supported. By this I mean that I've enabled the various settings for it to work based on what I've found online and it simply doesn't seem to be possible.

Is this something incredibly daft that I'm doing or not doing, or does it just not work in VS2019 and I should go back to VS2017? Thanks.

[image: Settings 1]

[image: Settings 2]

[image: Settings 3]

Immediately after running in debug mode, edit any line of any file to get this:

[image: Error message - immediately after running in debug mode, edit any line of any file to get this]

Comment: What is the type of your project? A net framework web project or a net core web project? Also, what is the target framework version of your project?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this something incredibly daft that I'm doing or not doing, or does
>   it just not work in VS2019 and I should go back to VS2017?

The premise of **Enable Edit and Continue** in **C#** is that you should set a breakpoint in that function or just in the `Page_Load` function. And when you do some code changes or any others,you should  move the cursor to the changes, and then VS will apply these changes while debugging.

Besides, when you do these changes and click Continue, these changes will be applied in the current debug process but you can not re-execute the breakpoint at the same time.

**Solution**

Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the method you want to debug. And when you write some changes later, please move the cursor into the changes so that the changes will be applied.

[image]

**Then** you can see the successful message about this.

[image]

**Note** that these changes are stored in a temporary repository for debugging purposes only and are not built into the output file at the same time. They are only built into the output file when you stop and restart debugging. And this is quite different from the C++ mode.

Hope it could help you.